# I can't ssh into my server after setting PubkeyAuthentication and RsaAuthentication to yes and PermitRootLogin to no

Tags: authentication, ssh, centos, root, centos6

I have a problem trying to `ssh` into my server after I made some changes in `sshd_config` file. I had changed the `PubkeyAuthentication` and `RsaAuthentication` to `YES` and `PermitRootLogin` to `NO`.

How can I access the server using ssh and edit `sshd_config` file ?

Answer (score 0):

Either with a user that is allowed to login and has setup the correct public keys (which you surely did beforehand?). Or via the server console.

If you find another way i think you should raise a bug report with sshd, as denying this is the goal of your configuration (with my basic ssh knowledge, though).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved I ssh into my server  using another account that has ssh acccess and then I used su command to login as a root and I accessed the server